# Implementing general timeouts

Tags: c, timer

I'm porting some code from C# to C. In the C# code there are three timers that fire if particular events take too long and they set flags that are checked next time a thread runs a bit of housekeeping.

The C is pure C, not C++, and will eventually be used on both Linux and in embedded targets, so I can't use any OS oriented stuff- simple soft timers. I started off using just an "enabled" flag and a due time for each timer, in ms, and when I call the housekeeping function I'll pass the current ms timer value to it. Then I started thinking of the wraparound issue and decided I wanted the start time as well, so if the present time isn't between the start time and the due time I know it's expired. And I want the default duration to be there as well, so it ends up being worth making a structure to represent a timer. And then making functions that work with pointers to these structures. And then it started me thinking I may be reinventing the wheel.

I don't see anything in the standard libraries that looks like this. Am I missing something? Is this just something that's just easier to do than to look for? :)

Comment: If you want it to work on an embedded system - yes, it is almost certainly easier to do than to search for a solution. Of course, most embedded systems actually have timer and counter hardware. At least a simple timer interrupt.

Comment: Ta for commenting. That's the way I went, just wanted to make sure I wasn't wasting work. Yeah embedded stuff tends to have a timer interrupt, but three is probably asking a bit much and adds hardware dependencies- I'm just passing the current ms timer value to my code and then it doesn't have to care about where that value's coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ta for commenting. That's the way I went, just wanted to make sure I wasn't wasting work. Yeah embedded stuff tends to have a timer interrupt, but three is probably asking a bit much and adds hardware dependencies- I'm just passing the current ms timer value to my code and then it doesn't have to care about where that value's coming from. –  Craig Graham